# Replacement for deprecated Shopware EntityRepositoryInterface is also deprecated

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

According to [Shopware 6.4.13.0 upgrade instructions](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.4.13.0/UPGRADE-6.4.md#internal-entity-repositories), `EntityRepositoryInterface` has been deprecated and should be replaced by `EntityRepository`. But `EntityRepository` is also marked as deprecated in my IDE, using the recommended development setup all upgraded to the latest versions:

- PhpStorm (2022.1.3 Build #PS-221.5921.28)
- Symfony Support plugin 2022.1.230
- Shopware plugin 4.4.3
- Shopware development setup cloned from [github.com/shopware/development](https://github.com/shopware/development)
- Shopware platform "6.4.9999999.9999999 Developer Version"
  loaded and upgraded by `psh` according to `composer.json` in development setup:

```json
    "require": {
        "shopware/platform": "6.4.x@dev || dev-trunk"
```

Deprecation note in my PhpStorm IDE:
[image: screenshot of deprecation message in PhpStorm IDE]

> Class 'EntityRepository' is deprecated
>
> `class EntityRepository implements EntityRepositoryInterface \Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository`
>
> Deprecated: 5.6.0
> Namespace:
> \Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\
>
> Source:
> development/vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/EntityRepository.php

How to handle the deprecation and what to use instead of `EntityRepositoryInterface` that will not be deprecated as well?

How to know if the IDE's deprecation notice can be safely ignored? I suppose that it can be ignored, as the mentioned version number "5.6.0" does not match any current or upcoming Shopware 6 release.

How to turn off misleading deprecation notices in my IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has been fixed with commit https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/99cf9093464d679f6abcb91bb68cc4205bc6ccf0

it has now only `@final` https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/EntityRepository.php#L29

Comment: Thanks! There are still a lot more deprecations though, after `git pull`, and `psh.phar update`, like `> bin/console dal:refresh:index
 15:03:56 INFO      [php] User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : Class "Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\RouteScope" is deprecated and will be removed in v6.5.0.0. Use ""@Route(defaults={"_routeScope"={"storefront"}})"" instead.` I have updated [my blog post](https://dev.to/ingosteinke/comment/1phgn) with the latest information. Thanks again!