# Replacement for deprecated Shopware 6 addExtension method?

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

[Adding custom data to a Shopware 6 pagelet, according to the latest documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-data-to-storefront-page#adding-data-to-the-page) can be done by calling `addExtension`:

```php
use Shopware\Storefront\Pagelet\Footer\FooterPageletLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

public function addActiveProductCount(FooterPageletLoadedEvent $event): void
{
  $event->getPagelet()->addExtension('product_count', $productCountResult);
```

But, although the [release note upgrade instructions](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.4.13.0/UPGRADE-6.4.md) do not mention a deprecation of `addExtension`, so does my IDE:

> Method 'addExtension' is deprecated
>
> `public function ExtendableTrait::addExtension(string $name, ?Struct $extension) void`
>
> Adds a new extension struct into the class storage. The passed name is used as unique identifier and has to be stored too.
>
> Deprecated: 5.6.0
>
> Implements: `ExtendableInterface::addExtension`
>
> Declared in: `Shopware\Core\Framework\Struct\ExtendableTrait`
>
> Source: [development/vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/Framework/Struct/ExtendableTrait.php](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.4.13.0/src/Core/Framework/Struct/ExtendableTrait.php)

Update: according to @cuong-huynh 's finding that the second parameter (`$extension`) must not be `null` anymore, I added a check to make sure we never pass `null`, but the method is still marked as deprecated in my IDE.

```php
if ($productCountResult) {
    $event->getPagelet()->addExtension('product_count', $productCountResult);
```

The above code shows `addExtension` as deprecated although `$productCountResult` should now be guaranteed never to be `null` thanks to the `if` check before.

Can someone either tell me which method to use instead and where to find the related documentation or else revert the deprecation flag in case `addExtension` has been marked as deprecated by mistake (similar to [EntityRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921494/replacement-for-deprecated-shopware-entityrepositoryinterface-is-also-deprecated) recently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to deprecated comment `@deprecated tag:v6.5.0 - second param $extension will not allow null anymore` as I understood that we still use that function but the second param can not be null.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, where did you find the comment? In the Shopware platform source code, @cuong-huynh ?

Comment: Yes, it's here: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.4.13.0/src/Core/Framework/Struct/ExtendableTrait.php#L20

Comment: But even if I ensure that the `$extension` is not null, the method still gets marked as deprecated.

Comment: the deprecated note will be removed since 6.5.0 then you can still use it.

Comment: So that's a PhpStorm question then? Maybe still the Shopware plugin could handle that and remove the misleading deprecation mark when the extension is used properly? Or can $shops still be null in this case? Why?